# Aptana Studio and tabbing through html nodes

Tags: html, eclipse, ide, aptana, aptana3

I love that I can tab through {}, [], (), etc. in Aptana but when I'm editing HTML and the existing node I'm currently editing is highlighted with the same light-grey border I inevitably try to step through it when I'm done by hitting tab and re-discover it doesn't work.

[image: Gets me every time]

Am I missing a really obvious keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift+Enter will jump to the next line (while also adding a new line after the current one), but I don't think there is a shortcut to cycle past it normally.